# how to write mongodb query for 'counting elements in sub-document'

Tags: mongodb-query

I have collection something like this...

```
{
    {
        id: 123,
        name: "abc",
        data: {
            type1: 0.78,
            type2: 0.89,
            type3: 0.67
        }
        purpose: "commercial"
    }, {
        id: 124,
        name: "pqrs",
        data: {
            type1: 0.34,
            type2: 0.78,
        }
        purpose: "open"
    }, {
        id: 125,
        name: "xtec",
        data: {
            type1: 0.48,
            type2: 0.56,
            type3: 0.67
            type4: 0.56,
            type5: 0.67
        }
        purpose: "some other"
    }
}
```

I would like to count the number of elements in "data" sub-document. Could any one post me mongodb query?

or I would like to display all the documents where the "data" sub-document length = 3

the below query doesn't work

```
db.test.find({$where : 'data.length = 3'});
```

Any help would greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Regards,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put your condition inside count method, you can use any condition you use in FIND method.

```
db.test.count({...});
```